# New-AzureRmADSpCredential Password that never expires

Tags: azure, powershell

Not sure if this is a bug or issue with the way I am using it but basically I am trying to add a non expiring password to an existing Azure Service Principal using New-AzureRmADSpCredential but no matter what i provide to the -EndDate parameter it never has an effect (always set to expire after 1 year)

example steps are:

```
$start = get-date
$end = $start.AddYears(99)
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -DisplayName SPTestnonExpirePW
$sp = Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "SPTestnonExpirePW"
New-AzureRmADSpCredential -ObjectId $sp.id -StartDate $start -EndDate $end -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PASSWORD" -Force -AsPlainText)
```

No matter what value I provide to -EndDate (as long as it is valid System.DateTime) the password is successfully created but with 1yr expiration

I have tried this on both PS core on linux and PS native on server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of search and tests, I got the same result with you and according to the test with postman I approve that it may be a bug with `New-AzureRmADSpCredential` Password.

Also, if you want to achieve credential never expires, you could try to use `New-AzureRmADAppCredential` to achieve that.

**Note**: The `ObjectId` here is not your `ServicePrincipal` objectid, it is the **App registered** objectId which is the same name with the `ServicePrincipal`.

```
$start = get-date
$end = $start.AddYears(150)
$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ObjectId xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -StartDate $start -EndDate $end -Password $SecureStringPassword
```

[image]

Comment: im using password auth not certificate so it isnt valid

Comment: Thanks for this, Ill have to test with New-AzureRmADAppCredential to see if it gets me to what I need but it should do the trick.

Comment: Just to finalize I wanted to clarify that using New-AzureRmADAppCredential instead of New-AzureRmADSpCredential provided the correct functionality for the authentication and with the non-expiring password. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you!